# Add an integer to every element of data frame

Tags: r

Say I have a data frame as follows

```
       rsi5    rsi10
1        NA       NA
2        NA       NA
3        NA       NA
4        NA       NA
5        NA       NA
6  44.96650       NA
7  39.68831       NA
8  28.35625       NA
9  37.77910       NA
10 53.54822       NA
11 52.05308 46.01867
12 80.44368 66.09973
13 60.88418 56.04507
14 53.59851 52.10633
15 46.45874 48.23648
```

I wish to simply add 1 (i.e. 9 becomes 10) to each non-NA element of this data frame. There is probably a very simple solution to this but simple arithmetics on dataframes do not seem to work in R giving very strange results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `+ 1` as you would expect. Below is a mock example as it wasn't worth copying your data for for this.

#### Step One: Create a data.frame

```
R> df <- data.frame(A=c(NA, 1, 2, 3), B=c(NA, NA, 12, 13))
R> df
   A  B
1 NA NA
2  1 NA
3  2 12
4  3 13
R>
```

#### Step Two: Add one

```
R> df + 1
   A  B
1 NA NA
2  2 NA
3  3 13
4  4 14
R>
```

Comment: I feel very stupid now. For some reason that solution did not seem to work for me at the time. But now it suddenly does.

Comment: I will accept your answer asap (can do that in 11 minutes)